# Shutdown Executor thread after awaitConfimation

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, executorservice

How to shutdown all threads created with ExecutorService after the

```
executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

is finished?

That's the max time threads can work, and if, in some case, any of them does not finish current task, shut it down and start again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `awaitTermination` returns true, then all the threads have been shutdown.

If `awaitTermination` returns false, then some of the threads are obviously not responding to interruption*, and apart from exiting the java process, there is not much you can do...

*If the tasks run by the threads are yours, make sure they respond to interruption by exiting quickly and `awaitTermination` will return promptly.

Comment: Can I somehow detect what threads are still running and shut them down manually?

Comment: @Ivan No, it is hidden within the implementation of the ExecutorService. If you had access to the threads you could try to stop them as a last resort, without a guarantee that it would succeed either (and with potential issues).

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do it. You can use a ThreadFactory which will create daemon threads, then run `awaitTermination` in the main thread, followed by `shutdownNow`. This will (hopefully) shut down the whole JVM, and there is little to nothing better than that in the given situation. Executing `System.exit()` is an even more drastic measure.

Note that interrupting or even stopping threads doesn't guarantee that they will actually terminate.

Comment: thank you on your response. I don't want to shutdown the whole JVM nor app at all. The problem is that some of the threads are doing some JDBC work and if any of those are not done, I can't start a connection to that database. I can use DB flag or something for that if there is no better option.

Comment: @assylias But classic `java.io` is non-interruptible, right? So it may still hang.

Answer (score 0):

You can call System.exit(1) to stop the application. If you dont want to exit then you should design your tasks so that they react to Thread.interrupt properly, there is no other way.

Comment: I don't want to terminate an app. It's in `while(true)` loop and I need to shutdown all threads before reentering the loop.